# How to find nth element using CSS having same id/class

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

if in a DOM we have multiple elements having same id/class, then how to locate a particular one using CSS e.g if we have " div class='aa' " repeated 90 times and i want to fetch 80th element, how to do it using CSS, i know how to do it using XPath ( (//div[@class='aa'])[80] ) but don't know in CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with same `id`. It is not valid. Also, CSS has no `nth-of-class` type selector. For finding nth element of a certain type you could use `nth-of-type`.

Comment: If you can do it using XPath, why don't you just use XPath?